# (WPF) Why is my databinding returning null to a class variable in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a signup page in my WPF project which uses bindings to retrieve the data from textboxes in my XAML. The Bindings are linked to records however when I try to use the data within these records it says that the records are null. I am trying to run a comparison between two of the variables inside the record however I can't because the record keeps returning null. (the viewmodel is definitely bound to the view I know through testing) Sorry if this is confusing this is my first question.

The following is the bindings for one my password boxes:

```xml
<usercontrols:BindablePasswordBox x:Name="inputPassword" 
                                  Password="{Binding Path=PasswordConfirm.InitialPassword, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<usercontrols:BindablePasswordBox x:Name="inputPasswordConfirm" 
                                  Password="{Binding Path=PasswordConfirm.SecondaryPassword, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

This is the declaration of the record inside the viewmodel:

```cs
public PasswordConfirm PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
```

and this is the separate record / class which it is using:

```cs
internal class PasswordConfirm : ViewModelBaseClass
{
    private string _initialPassword;

    public string InitialPassword
    {
        get { return _initialPassword; }
        set { _initialPassword = value; OnPropertyChanged("InitialPassword"); }
    }

    private string _secondaryPassword;

    public string SecondaryPassword
    {
        get { return _secondaryPassword; }
        set { _secondaryPassword = value; OnPropertyChanged("SecondaryPassword"); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<PasswordConfirm> _passwordConfirmRecords;

    public ObservableCollection<PasswordConfirm> PasswordConfirmRecords
    {
        get { return _passwordConfirmRecords; }
        set { _passwordConfirmRecords = value; OnPropertyChanged("PasswordConfirmRecords"); }
    }

    private void PasswordConfirm_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("PasswordConfirmRecords");
    }
}
```

So for example when I try to run this it will always says that `UserRecord` is null

```cs
if (PasswordConfirm != null)
{
    if (PasswordConfirm.InitialPassword == PasswordConfirm.SecondaryPassword)
    {
        MainWindowVM mainVM = (MainWindowVM)Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext;
        mainVM.CurrentDisplayPage = destinationPage;
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorMsg = "Passwords do not match";
    }
}
else
{
    ErrorMsg = "Please fill all fields";
}
```

again sorry if this is confusing I have tried to explain as best I can

Comment: You've declared a UserRecord property in your view model, but you haven't shown any code that actually sets that property, so it makes sense that it's null. You need something to set it, for example `UserRecord = new UserRecord()`

Comment: Why the type of FirstName property is int whereas the type of TextBox.Text is string? It should cause an error when the former property is updated by the binding.

Comment: sorry I had the wrong class there It is now updated

Comment: When you say the record keeps returning null, what do you mean? What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Is your code reaching the line `ErrorMsg = "Please fill all fields";`?

Comment: Yes, it keep reaching that :(

Comment: When you do this in your view model: `public PasswordConfirm PasswordConfirm { get; set; }` you are declaring a Property named `PasswordConfirm` but it defaults to null. You need to initialize it. For example, in the constructor of your view model do `PasswordConfirm = new PasswordConfirm();`

Comment: yes that was it, did not know it was so simple thanks!